# Can anyone suggest a way that I can formaly acknowlge users in a piece of accademic work?

Tags: discussion

Over the years I have learnt a great deal from MM SE, in fact I think it has one of the best communities I have experienced out of the ones I have used/lurked on. Several regular and experienced users, but one in particular, have educated me and not just in Mathematica but in statistics also.

I'd quite like to acknowledge them when I submit my thesis -- it seems only fair. But obviously some users want to maintain anonymity. Is there a way I can message a user to see if they: a) even want to be acknowledged b) how they would prefer to be acknowledged.

Comment: [Related meta.SE discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110006); see also the questions linked from it.